# Executing a Z3 script in command line prompt

Tags: z3

I have a very simple example Z3 program which is as follows:

```
(declare-const a Int)
(declare-fun f (Int Bool) Int)
(assert (> a 10))
(assert (< (f a true) 100))
(check-sat)
```

This sample program can be executed in the Z3 online compiler and there are no problems. But when I want to execute the same program using command line prompt with the following command:

```
Z3 <script path>
```

I get the error saying:

```
ERROR: line 1 column 21: could not match expression to benchmark .
```

and this error is repeated for each line in the program.
Can anyone help me to see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

You're using SMT2 format. Call

```
z3 -smt2 <script path>
```

Comment: Thanks that was great. One other question do you know how I can generate all the different variations for possible answers of the model?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is a code in Z3 python. I can't use it in normal Z3 syntax

Comment: Z3 will produce only one model, but after the first time, you can add a constraint that excludes the previous model (e.g., ... (and (not (= x 3))); that's essentially what the Python code in the other post does.